# The derivative of a $C^{1}$ function and sequences

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, complex-analysis, functional-analysis, derivatives

Let $f \in C^{1}(\mathbb{R})$ and $r \in \mathbb{R}$. Also consider $\{h_{n}\}, \{a_n\}$ sequences in $\mathbb{R}$ such that $h_{n} \rightarrow 0$ and $a_n \rightarrow r$. Is it true that
$$
f'(r) = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{f(a_n + h_n) - f(a_n)}{h_n} \quad?
$$
This question appeared when I tried to prove the fallowing:
Let $\Omega$ be a bounded domain in $\mathbb{R}^N$ and $f : \overline{\Omega} \times \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(\cdot, s)$ is continous for each $s \in \mathbb{R}$ and $f(x, \cdot) \in C^{1}(\mathbb{R})$ for each $x \in \overline{\Omega}$. In addiction, let $u,v \in C^{2}(\Omega)\cap C^{1}(\overline{\Omega})$. Then, if $u(x_0) = v(x_0) =: r $, for some $x_0 \in \overline{\Omega}$ and $\{x_n\}$ is a sequence in $\overline{\Omega}$ converging to $x_0$, then
$$
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{f(x_n,u(x_n)) - f(x_n, v(x_n))}{u(x_n) - v(x_n)} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial s}(x_0,r).
$$

Comment: Yes, and it it is an easy consequence of Mean Value Theorem.

Comment: Thank you! I did it!